# Combining two dataframes with same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

1. `feelingsDF` with columns `'feeling', 'count', 'code'`.
2. `countryDF` with columns `'feeling', 'countryCount'`.

How do I make another dataframe that takes the columns from `countryDF` and combines it with the `code` column in `feelingsDF`?

I'm guessing you would need to somehow use same `feeling` column in `feelingsDF` to combine them and match sure the same `code` matches the same feeling.

I want the three columns to appear as:

```
[feeling][countryCount][code]
```

Comment: Does this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) solve your problem?

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you tried?

Comment: I haven't attempted it yet because I don't even know where to start. These aer what the two dataframes look like: https://ibb.co/V27nzCZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining the two dataframes by the column 'feeling'. Assuming you only want the entries in 'feeling' that are common to both dataframes, you would want to do an inner join.

Here is a similar example with two dfs:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'feeling': ['happy', 'sad', 'angry', 'upset', 'wow'], 'col1': [1,2,3,4,5]})
y = pd.DataFrame({'feeling': ['okay', 'happy', 'sad', 'not', 'wow'], 'col2': [20,23,44,10,15]})
x.merge(y,how='inner', on='feeling')
```

Output:

```
  feeling  col1  col2
0   happy     1    23
1     sad     2    44
2     wow     5    15
```

To drop the 'count' column, select the other columns of feelingsDF, and then sort by the 'countryCount' column. Note that this will leave your index out of order, but you can reindex the combined_df afterwards.

```
combined_df = feelingsDF[['feeling', 'code']].merge(countryDF, how='inner', on='feeling').sort_values('countryCount')
# To reset the index after sorting:
combined_df = combined_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to take out the 'count' column and just have 'countryCount'? Also, is there a way to resort the list by the countryCount?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can join two dataframes using pd.merge. Assuming that you want to join on the  *feeling* column, you can use:

```
df= pd.merge(feelingsDF, countryDF, on='feeling', how='left')
```

See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for pd.merge to understand how to use the on and how parameters.

```
feelingsDF = pd.DataFrame([{'feeling':1,'count':10,'code':'X'}, 
{'feeling':2,'count':5,'code':'Y'},{'feeling':3,'count':1,'code':'Z'}])

   feeling  count code
0        1     10    X
1        2      5    Y
2        3      1    Z

countryDF = pd.DataFrame([{'feeling':1,'country':'US'},{'feeling':2,'country':'UK'},{'feeling':3,'country':'DE'}])

   feeling country
0        1      US
1        2      UK
2        3      DE

df= pd.merge(feelingsDF, countryDF, on='feeling', how='left')

   feeling  count code country
0        1     10    X      US
1        2      5    Y      UK
2        3      1    Z      DE
```